# Laravel - Banco de dados - dados únicos somente a partir do id do usuário logado

Tags: php, laravel-5, validação

Estou tendo um problema no *Laravel*, na verificação dos dados únicos, eu quero que verifique se dados são únicos somente no id do usuário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tenho uma tabela chamada empresas_cadastradas, e o que eu quero que faça é por exemplo digito o nome da empresa SouGamerrr, e com isso ele vai fazer a validação e vai ver se na coluna id = 3 na coluna nome existe o nome da empresa e vai retornar o erro dizendo que já existe.
Mas o que ocorre é, ele ignora o id 3 e verifica nos outros e assim atualiza mesmo existindo.

Meu código utilizado:

```
 case 'PUT':
    case 'PATCH':
    {
         return[
        'nome' => 'required|string|max:150|unique:empresas_cadastradas,id,'.Auth::id(),
        'email_principal' => 'required|string|email|max:80|unique:empresas_cadastradas,email_principal,'.Auth::id(),
        'telefone'    => 'string|max:25|required',
        'celular'    => 'string|max:25|required',
        'endereco'    => 'string|max:150|required',
        'numero'    => 'string|max:25|required',
        'bairro'    => 'string|max:100|required',
        'complemento'    => 'string|max:150|required',
        'cnpj'    => 'string|max:20|unique:empresas_cadastradas,cnpj,'.Auth::id(),
        'resumo'    => 'required|string|max:500|required',
        'avatar' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg|max:2048',
    ];

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema, estarei deixando a resolução.

em AppServiceProvider.php adicione esse código.

```
public function boot(){

  /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| UNICO ID
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| verifica no banco de dados se existe os dados somente do usuario logado
|  $atribute == nome do campo input(name) - Valor vem automatico
|  $value == valor do name($atribute) - Valor vem automatico
| $parameters == sao os parametros como por exemplo:
| uniqui_for_id_all:primeiro_parametro,valor_primeiro_parametro
| 
|
*/
     Validator::extend('uniqui_for_id', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {

        $existe = DB::table($parameters[0])->where([
            [$parameters[1], '=', $parameters[2]],
            [$parameters[3], '!=', $parameters[4]],
            [$attribute, '=',  $value]
        ])->first();

        if(!$existe){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    });

             /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| UNICO ID
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| verifica no banco de dados se existe os dados comparando com todos execao 
| ele mesmo
| 
|
*/

     Validator::extend('uniqui_for_id_all', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {


        $existe = DB::table($parameters[0])->where([
            [$parameters[1], '!=', $parameters[2]],
            [$attribute, '=',  $value]
        ])->first();

        if(!$existe){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

}

E em seu arquivo de validação(REQUEST) dos campos adicione:

```
uniqui_for_id:NOME_DO_BANCO_DE_DADOS,PRIMEIRA_COLUNA_NOME,PRIMEIRA_COLUNA_VALOR,SEGUNDA_COLUNA_NOME,SEGUNDA_COLUNA_VALOR
```

Na segunda validação:

```
uniqui_for_id:NOME_DO_BANCO_DE_DADOS,PRIMEIRA_COLUNA_NOME,PRIMEIRA_COLUNA_VALOR
```

e vá em lang/en ou /lang/pt_br(a lingua definida)-> validation.php

adicione:

```
 'custom' => [
    'nome' => [
        'uniqui_for_id' => 'O campo :attribute já está sendo utilizado.',
        'uniqui_for_id_all' => 'O campo :attribute já está sendo utilizado.',
    ],
    'email_principal' => [
        'uniqui_for_id' => 'O campo :attribute já está sendo utilizado.',
        'uniqui_for_id_all' => 'O campo :attribute já está sendo utilizado.',
    ],
    'telefone' => [
        'uniqui_for_id' => 'O campo :attribute já está sendo utilizado.',
        'uniqui_for_id_all' => 'O campo :attribute já está sendo utilizado.',
    ],
    'celular' => [
        'uniqui_for_id' => 'O campo :attribute já está sendo utilizado.',
        'uniqui_for_id_all' => 'O campo :attribute já está sendo utilizado.',
    ],
    'cnpj' => [
        'uniqui_for_id' => 'O campo :attribute já está sendo utilizado.',
        'uniqui_for_id_all' => 'O campo :attribute já está sendo utilizado.',
    ],
],
```

substitua e coloque o nome da sua validação: uniqui_for_id
substitua e coloque o nome dos campos(inputs ou texarea, etc):nome